# How to run a command every time Cruise Control .NET (ccnet) has automatically checked out source?

Tags: .net, svn, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Basically I want to run a script checking for the existence of a certain filetype at each new revision.

Subversion is used for source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project's configuration (within `ccnet.config`) there is a `<tasks>` element within which you can define various actions that are taken whenever an integration is triggered.  In your case, you would set up a trigger that looked something like this:

```
<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger name="continuous" 
                   seconds="60"
                   buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
</triggers>
```

There are several types of tasks included with CruiseControl.NET.  The documentation includes a [comprehensive list](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Task+Blocks) that explains how they are to be used, and what options are available.